# Static methods/properties in c++cli interface and implementation classes

Tags: c#, interface, static, c++-cli

I'm trying to create an interface to a class i have in c++cli which is then consumed in c#.

Basically, I want to do something along the lines of:

```
public interface class IFoo
{
   static int method();

};

public ref class Foo : public IFoo
{
   static int method() { return 0; }   
};
```

So obviously this is incorrect, as there will be errors when trying to compile. I've tried numerous different ways, to no avail.

In c#, i would do the following:

```
public interface IFooCSharp
{
    int method();
}

public class FooCSharp : IFooCSharp
{
   public static int method() { return 0 };

   int IFooSharp.method() { return FooCSharp.method(); }
}
```

So i was hoping to see if there was an equivalent way to do this in c++cli?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't have static members in an interface.

You figured out the right way to do this in C#: through an explicit interface implementation, you just need the [right syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235235.aspx) for C++/CLI:

```cpp
public interface class IFoo
{
    int method();
};

public ref class Foo : public IFoo
{
    static int method() { return 0; }

    virtual int methodInterface() sealed = IFoo::method { return method(); }
};
```

Unlike in C#, you need to provide a name for your method, even though you don't intend to use it directly.

---

Here's the syntax for properties:

```
public interface class IFoo
{
    property int prop;
};

public ref class Foo : public IFoo
{
    property int propInterface {
        virtual int get() sealed = IFoo::prop::get { return 0; }
        virtual void set(int value) sealed = IFoo::prop::set { /* whatever */ }
    };
};
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank-you. It was providing the name for the method that was hindering me.

Comment: virtual int myprop1method() = IFoo::myProp1::get { return Foo::prop1; }

Comment: @user2477533 I've added the syntax for properties to the answer, I also added `sealed` to avoid a compiler warning (*a private virtual method of a ref class or value class should be marked 'sealed'*).